# Pythonanywhere: Running Django shell in .ipynb Python notebook

Tags: python, django, shell, jupyter-notebook, pythonanywhere

I am running Django on [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com). I have created a .ipynb notebook in the same directory having manage.py file.

I have added the following code:

```
import csv, os,sys
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settingsfile")
import django
django.setup()
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

from app.models import model_one, model_two
```

But am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class app.models.the_model doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Can some someone please tell me how to correct it, and what is the best way to run python shell in iPython notebook? TIA

Comment: Can you change this line: `from app.models import model_one, model_two` to this `from your_project_name.app.models import model_one, model_two` ? Where `your_project_name` put the name of your django project.

Comment: check [this plugin](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can use a jupyter notebook with `django manage.py shell_plus --notebook`

Comment: @JohnMoutafis ... adding from your_project_name.app.models import model_one, model_two .... gives the error:

`ImportError: No module named 'your_project_name.app'`

Comment: @alfonso.kim I tried `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`  in bash, but got the following error:

`[W 19:20:54.805 NotebookApp] Config option `debug` not recognized by `NotebookApp`.`

then some text... followed by...


`[C 19:20:54.818 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 19:20:54.818 NotebookApp] The 'kernel_spec_manager_class' trait of <notebook.notebookapp.NotebookApp object at 0x7fab75d71110> instance must be a
 type, but 'environment_kernels.EnvironmentKernelSpecManager' could not be imported`

Comment: @chhibbz wow!, the problem must be `pythonanywhere`. I use `shell_plus` in all my projects without any issue. I've never used `pythonanywhere`

Comment: What happens if you go back to your original code, but add the directory containing the `manage.py` file to `sys.path`?